# How to use Google Analytics in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-analytics, ionic3

I want to implement Google Analytics in my application to know how many users access my application in real time, but I'm having some difficulties. In the Google Analytics panel, the following message appears (in Portuguese):

[image]

And I'm following Ionic's documentation, but I can not add in my application, could someone give me a "north" about it?

And this is code of documentation

```
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics';

constructor(private ga: GoogleAnalytics) { }

...

this.ga.startTrackerWithId('YOUR_TRACKER_ID')
   .then(() => {
     console.log('Google analytics is ready now');
      this.ga.trackView('test');
     // Tracker is ready
     // You can now track pages or set additional information such as AppVersion or UserId
   })
   .catch(e => console.log('Error starting GoogleAnalytics', e))
```